# java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.rebind disallowed; origin /10.0.0.71 is non-local host

Tags: java, rmi, remote-access, remote-server

I have a simple client/server Calculator application using RMI.  The server and the client are in different linux machines.  Client ip is 10.0.0.71 and server ip is 10.0.1.100.

This is the remote interface:

```
package com.simplecalc.commons;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Calculator extends Remote {
    public float add(float a, float b) throws RemoteException;
}
```

This is the server side code implementing the remote interface:

```
package com.simplecalc.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public float add(float a, float b) throws RemoteException {
        float result = a + b;
        System.out.println("$ (" + a + " + " + b + ") = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the server side code for running the application:

```
package com.simplecalc.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class Server {

    private static void setPolicy() {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:///calculator.policy");
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        setPolicy();
        int port = 1099;
        Calculator engine = new CalculatorImpl();
        Calculator stub = (Calculator) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
        System.out.println("Registering calculator object ...");
        registry.rebind(Calculator.class.getSimpleName(), stub);
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the client to invoke the calculator:

```
package com.simplecalc.client;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class CalculatorClient {

    private static void setPolicy() {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:///calculator.policy");
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        setPolicy();
        int port = 1099;
        String server="10.0.1.100";

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(server, port);
        Calculator calculator = (Calculator) registry.lookup(Calculator.class.getSimpleName());
        registry.rebind(server, calculator);
        float result = calculator.add(10F, 5F);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

This is the `calculator.policy` file:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "10.0.0.71:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:80", "connect, resolve";
};
```

I compiled the server code and successfully started the rmiregistry like this:

```
cd server_classes_directory
rmiregistry 1099 &
```

Then I successfully ran the class `com.simplecalc.server.Server`

When I run the class `com.simplecalc.client.CalculatorClient` I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server     thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.rebind disallowed; origin /10.0.0.71 is non-local host
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(    StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:155)
    at com.simplecalc.client.CalculatorClient.main(CalculatorClient.java:27)
Caused by: java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.rebind disallowed; origin /10.0.0.71 is     non-local host
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.checkAccess(RegistryImpl.java:350)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:468)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:300)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem.

1. The thing is that the way I used to register and lookup the rmi service only work when client and server are in the same machine.
2. Is not necessary to instantiate `SecurityManager`
3. The remote interface implementation must extends `UnicastRemoteObject`
4. I totally open the java security policies.

This is the new remote interface implementation:

```
package com.simplecalc.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class CalculatorImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public float add(float a, float b) throws RemoteException {
        float result = a + b;
        System.out.println("$ (" + a + " + " + b + ") = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the new server class:

```
package com.simplecalc.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        final int port = 1099;
        final String serverIp = "10.0.1.100";
        final String serviceName = Calculator.class.getSimpleName();
        final String url = "rmi://" + serverIp + ":" + port + "/" + serviceName;

        System.out.println("Registering calculator object ...");
        CalculatorImpl engine = new CalculatorImpl();
        Naming.rebind(url, engine);
        System.out.println("Server listening on " + url);
    }
}
```

This is the new client class:

```
package com.simplecalc.client;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

import com.simplecalc.commons.Calculator;

public class CalculatorClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        final int port = 1099;
        final String serverIp = "10.0.1.100";
        final String serviceName = Calculator.class.getSimpleName();
        final String url = "rmi://" + serverIp + ":" + port + "/" + serviceName;

        Calculator calculator = (Calculator) Naming.lookup(url);
        float result = calculator.add(10F, 5F);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

The `calculator.policy` file:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: Finally? *You* found? (1) you had already been told, and is the only thing you needed to do here. (2) is true here, but not in all cases, and wasn't causing this problem. (3) is incorrect: you can export it manually, as described here. (4) is completely irrelevant, as you now don't have a SecurityManager. – EJP 14 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as the error says, you can't bind, rebind, or unbind to/from a remote registry. You have to be running in the same host. This is an elementary security measure of RMI.

But your client shouldn't be doing a bind in the first place. It doesn't make sense. All it is trying to do is rebind the server it just looked up, into the same registry. Just remove it.

Comment: In some cases, such as containerization, you actually want to bind from a remote registry. Don't assume every question on StackOverflow is an XY problem, please.